# C# Generic with function calls

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I've read on the MSDN site that c# templates(generics) are not the same as in c++. I have two different objects, which has the Component transform is it possible to somehow feed it with the "Objects" instead of the specific component?

I would like to do a call like below, as both objects has a transform component.

```
collisionCheck(Me, this)
```

Otherwise I can do it as well with:

```
collisionCheck(Me.transform, this.transform)
```

but I want to hide as much as possible from the front-end. (example below is without feeding transform component)

```
public void collisionCheck(object enemy, object me){
    if(me.transform.x < enemy.transform.x)
        print("foo");
}
```

If you have any tips, it would be nice!

Answer (score 3):

You probably need inheritance here and not generics.

```
public interface IPositioned
{
  float X { get; }
  float Y { get; }
}

public class Me: IPositioned { /* ... */ }
public class Enemy: IPositioned { /* ... */ }

/* ... */
public void CollisionCheck(IPositioned me, IPositioned enemy)
{
   if (me.X < enemy.X)
   {
      Console.Write("foo");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something like this. But I agree that you probably want to have a CollisionCheck implementation on a base class and use inheritance as well.

```
public class Transform
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasTransform
{
    Transform SomeTransform { get; set; }
}

public class You : IHasTransform
{
    public Transform SomeTransform { get; set; }
}

public class Me : IHasTransform
{
    public Transform SomeTransform { get; set; }

    public void CollisionCheck<T>(T other) where T : IHasTransform
    {
        if (this.SomeTransform.X < other.SomeTransform.X)
            Console.WriteLine("foo");
    }
}
```